# Es posible tener múltiples backgrounds en Capybara - Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, test, rubygems, cucumber, capybara

Estoy haciendo algunas pruebas para comprobar mi proyecto.

Estoy trabajando con dos tipos de usuarios:

- usuario regular
- usuario administrador

Como usuario regular, puedo crear, ver mis propios informes, etc.. pero no puedo ver los informes de otros usuarios.

Como administrador, puedo ver todos los informes creados.

Por lo tanto, necesito tener dos backgrounds diferentes en la misma .feature para checkear el informe creado por un usuario normal y posteriormente listar ese informe creado por un usuario normal pero accediendo como administrador.

```
 Feature: Manage Reports

  Background:
    Given a calendar with yesterday
    Given a logged in user

  # UPDATE REPORTS
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Ufff, siglos que no uso Cucumber. No has especificado si usas alguna gema de autenticación/autorización en especial o implementaste tu propio sistema. En cualquier caso, en [la wiki de devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Cucumber) sale un ejemplo que podrías usar como modelo para esto.

Comment: Para loguearme lo hago mediante google. Pero no es necesario saberlo, simplemente ver si se pueden tener dos backgrounds diferentes  en el mismo archivo .feature o no.

Comment: La respuesta corta es "sí, es posible". Pero supongo que querrás saber cómo hacerlo. Para ello necesitamos saber qué gema o similar usas para autenticar. Mencionas Google, así que ¿igual es Omniauth? ¿O haces otra cosa? Este es el detalle importante. Cucumber no es relevante, puesto que es solo un lenguaje intermediario, y no determina cómo interactúas con la aplicación, ni cómo almacenas el estado del script.